# PHP if statment question

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have a simple question. So I have this code in my php file:

```
if(empty($_POST['height'])) { 
$width = '385';
}
```

is it possible to do something like this?

if value of ($_POST['height'] is 'height' then $width ='385'; instead of if empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean;

```
if (!empty($_POST['height']) && $_POST['height'] == 'height') {
    $width = '385';
}
```

**Update**

Based on the comment, the solution would be:

```
if (array_key_exists('height', $_POST) && $_POST['height'] == 'height') {
    $width = '385';
}
```

Comment: You forgot a $ sign in the width.

Comment: @Dimitry and @Nican YES! thanks! I knew it was really simple.

Comment: just one more question @Dimitry would it be possible to do this code without the empty option? so its just when .$_POST['height'. is equal to 'height' then do this because the code you have now does it for when its empty as well as when its 'height'. does that make sense?

Comment: usr, check the revision. It still needs to check that $_POST has 'height', and, if it does have it, checks the value.

Comment: are you talking about isset($var)?